# Extract what's inside of "span" that's inside of a class

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a way to set the variable z as 500

I tried the following so far:

```
z = +(document.getElementsByClassName("time span").innerHTML)
```

But it gives me an output of NaN

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have a NodeList of elements – even if it's a NodeList of only one element – from which you're trying to retrieve the `innerHTML` property; this can't work.

Furthermore you have a `<span>` within the node from which you're retrieving the `innerHTML`; that will be returned in the string, giving (approximately):

```
<span>500</span>
```

Which will not be parsed as a number; so instead use an index to retrieve the property from a single node and use `textContent` to retrieve the text instead of the HTML:

```
z = document.getElementsByClassName("time")[0].textContent;
```

```js
var z = document.getElementsByClassName('time')[0].textContent;
console.log(z)
```

```html
<div class="time">Time: <span>500</span></div>
```

Or retrieve only a single node:

```
z = document.querySelector(".time").textContent;
```

```js
var z = document.querySelector('.time').textContent;
console.log(z)
```

```html
<div class="time">Time: <span>500</span></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `querySelector()` instead and select `.time span`

```js
var z = document.querySelector('.time span').innerHTML;
console.log(z)
```

```html
<div class="time">Time: <span>500</span></div>
```

In case you want to add time from multiple `span`'s to z var you can use `querySelectorAll()` which returns **NodeList** and transform it to array and then use `forEach` loop and add each value of span to z

```js
var z = 0;

Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.time span')).forEach(function(e) {
  z += Number(e.innerHTML);
});
console.log(z)
```

```html
<div class="time">Time: <span>500</span>
</div>
<div class="time">Time: <span>200</span>
</div>
```